# Select from Many-to-Many with GroupBy

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many

I have three entities:
Cue(id, name)
Reaction(id, name)
Freqs(id, cue_id FK, reaction_id FK, some_other_data)

I want to count number of (cue, reaction) pairs like (cue.name, reaction.name, count)
I already wrote a query

```
SELECT
  a.cue_id, 
  a.reaction_id,
  Count(*) as freq
FROM 
  rdb_freqs a 
  JOIN rdb_reaction b ON a.cue_id=b.id
  JOIN rdb_cue c ON a.reaction_id=c.id
GROUP BY a.cue_id, a.reaction_id
ORDER BY freq DESC;
```

But how should I replace 'id' with 'name'?

Comment: What is your database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct
  c.name cue_name,
  b.name reaction_name, 

 (SELECT
  Count(*)
  FROM 
  rdb_freqs a1
  where 
  a1.cue_id =  a.cue_id and 
  a1.reaction_id = a.reaction_id 
  ) as count
FROM 
  rdb_freqs a 
  inner JOIN rdb_reaction b ON a.reaction_id = b.id
  inner JOIN rdb_cue c ON a.cue_id = c.id
  order by count desc
```

[**SQLfiddle sample**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/785f6/15) (written in oracle)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  c.name as cue_name,
  b.name as reacion_name,
  Count(*) as freq
FROM 
  rdb_freqs a 
  JOIN rdb_reaction b ON a.cue_id=b.id
  JOIN rdb_cue c ON a.reaction_id=c.id
GROUP BY c.name, b.name
ORDER BY freq DESC;
```

Comment: I've already tried it, but for some reasons I got absolutely different and incorrect results

Comment: @Ivri care to elaborate?

Comment: I got correct frequency, but incorrect cue_name and reaction_name.May be it's a problem with join? I'll try to check this ...

Comment: @Ivri can you supply sample data and results? This should be correct.

Comment: If there is duplicate names in cue or reaction, grouping on the names will cause incorrect result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
FROM rdb_freq f
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      a.cue_id, 
      a.reaction_id,
      Count(*) as freq
    FROM 
      rdb_freqs a 
      JOIN rdb_reaction b ON a.cue_id=b.id
      JOIN rdb_cue c ON a.reaction_id=c.id
    GROUP BY a.cue_id, a.reaction_id
        ) AS tot ON f.cue_id = tot.cue_id
    INNER JOIN reaction
```